# Button toggle-topbar not working in Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

Why Menu button not workig?

He does not react to clicks.

JS errors in the browser console is not.

My code:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
<ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="/testtop/">GamingTop</a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
</ul>
<section class="top-bar-section"><ul class="left"><li><a href="/testtop/tops/">Рейтинги</a></li><li><a href="/testtop/games/">Игры</a></li><li><a href="/testtop/about/">О нас</a></li></ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
            <a href="/testtop/profile">guyasyou@gmail.com</a>
            <ul class="dropdown"><li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)">Back</a></h5></li>
                <li><a href="/testtop/profile">Профиль</a></li>
                <li><a href="/testtop/project/">Мои сервера</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/testtop/auth/logout">Выйти</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Included JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/testtop/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/testtop/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you post the whole html of your page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by the version of your jQuery. Try to use the latest version and don't forget to close the nav tag.
Its okay with this code :

Header :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css">
```

Code :

```
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="/testtop/">GamingTop</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section"><ul class="left"><li><a href="/testtop/tops/">Рейтинги</a></li><li><a href="/testtop/games/">Игры</a></li><li><a href="/testtop/about/">О нас</a></li></ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
                <a href="/testtop/profile">guyasyou@gmail.com</a>
                <ul class="dropdown"><li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)">Back</a></h5></li>
                    <li><a href="/testtop/profile">Профиль</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/testtop/project/">Мои сервера</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/testtop/auth/logout">Выйти</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
```

Before closing your body tag :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```